# how to identify which `span` has been clicked in order to change the css property of it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a set of `span` tags (for color blocks) and inside each, I have another `span tag` (for icons). I want to change the `css` property of an icon from `display:none` to `display:block` as soon as one of the colors is clicked. The condition being that when one of the icons has `display:block` then the rest should be hidden.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruju/qsJ3c/35/) to get a better idea of what I mean

So here is what i mean in steps:

1. The `colors' span/block` should be clicked
2. When one of them is clicked , the `icon` should be displayed
3. When another one of the colors is clicked, icon should be displayed but the previous icon that was displayed should now be hidded

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 99% of the time your external files `<link>` and `<script>` need to load only once. You have duplicates of Bootstrap and 2 versions of jQuery. You should really read a tutorial.

Comment: agreed with @zer00ne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `$(".colors").click(function(){` handler to `$(document).on('click', '.colors', function(){` and do your show/hide logic in the click event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.colors', function(){
  //display "fa fa-check" on the clicked div and hide it on the rest
  $('.fa.fa-check').hide();
  $('.fa.fa-check', $(this)).show();
});
```

Comment: Hi @sanjana. if this has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. There is no obligation to do this, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple jquery in this:

select your label tag as well as each color div with id selector

```
<div id="label"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
```

**then in jquery:**

```
<script>
    $("#red").click(function(){
   $("#label").css("background-color","red");
})

</script>
```

Comment: so i should use if else or switch case to display the icon in only of the divs?

Answer (score 0):

You can always go for a simpler pure CSS solution, adding radio-buttons and using labels instead of spans for your colors, then switching the visibility of the checked option.

```
    .fa.fa-check{
        visibility: hidden;
        color:white;
        padding-top: 8px; 
        padding-left:14px;
        font-size:15px;
    }
.colors{
        cursor:pointer;
        width:42px; 
        height:30px;
        margin-right:3px;
        border-radius:3px; 
        display:inline-block;
    }

.option{display:none;}

.option:checked + label span{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qsJ3c/44/